# I am trying to create a new dataframe using another dataframe consisting of values

Tags: python, pandas

```
temp['DateTime']= Total_12hravg_all[index_end, 'DateTime']
```

`temp` is a new dataframe

`Total_12hravg_all` is dataframe from which i want a particluar value of the row of column using index_end as a variable. `Datetime` is a column in `Total_12hravg_all` which is present as a index in the `dataframe` and i actually need `DateTime` value.

But getting Syntax error.

Comment: Use `.loc` as `Total_12hravg_all.loc[index_end, 'DateTime']`

Comment: Share with us the error you're getting and some of the rows of the data frames you're working on. Refer to the markdown help on how you reproduce examples.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: you will also need to declare temp as a df object.
temp = pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: @pygo in output the the value of datetime should be append in Datetime column of temp e.g if index_end has 81 value then the Total_12hravg_all['Datetime'] value of that row should be added to temp['datetime']. note: datetime of Total_12hravg_all is Index.

Comment: try with `df.groupby('colomn_of_Intrest')` , can you show the example dataset you have and desired new dataset output to get the better answers?

Answer (score 1):

Example : The columns of interest are company_id (string) and company_score (float).

So, You can use `groupby` **company_id** column and convert its result into a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "company_id": ["AA", "AB", "AA", "CD", "AB"],
...     "company_score": [.07, .08, .06, .0003, .09],
...     "company_region": ["NW", "NE", "NW", "NW", "NE"]})
>>> df
  company_id company_region  company_score
0         AA             NW         0.0700
1         AB             NE         0.0800
2         AA             NW         0.0600
3         CD             NW         0.0003
4         AB             NE         0.0900
>>> dict_of_companies = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('company_id')}

>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dict_of_companies)
{'AA':   company_id company_region  company_score
0         AA             NW           0.07
2         AA             NW           0.06,
 'AB':   company_id company_region  company_score
1         AB             NE           0.08
4         AB             NE           0.09,
 'CD':   company_id company_region  company_score
3         CD             NW         0.0003}
>>>
```

Comment: Or `dict(tuple(df.groupby('company_id')))`